# VMWare Player side-by-side VirtualBox

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox, vmware-player

Can I have the latest version of VMWare Player with the latest version of VirtualBox installed side-by-side on the same machine on Windows 7?

Are there any conflicts? AFAIK, they both create virtual network adapters, etc.

Comment: You can have both installed side-by-side with no problems, you will just have two different network adaptors. I don't believe you can run both at the same time due to conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Since they both create their own version of virtual network adapters, there should not be any conflicts from that, no.

Rather, think of any potentially shared resources, and direct hardware access to, for instance, USB or video.

You will have problems with those.

Comment: I will not run the side-by-side, just I will have to install them side-by-side.